# reproducing a Kubuntu 14.04 system on another laptop

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to copy my installation of Kubuntu 14.04 from laptop A to laptop B.  So on B I created a new user U, then copied (with -a) /home/U on A to /home/U on B.  I also changed the ownership of all the copied files to be U on B with **chown**.  In addition, I copied the directory **/tmp/kde-U**. I tried to copy the directory **socket-U** but it could not be copied because of the socket entries in it.

I could log in to the new account for U and could see the desktop, which appeared to be correct.  But clicking on the desktop icons did nothing.  What more do I need to do?

Comment: Do you want to copy just the user data, such as documents, music, etc. or are you trying to copy the system files and folders as well? Do the two laptops have the identical graphics and WiFi chips? These chips may be different even for the same make and model of laptop made on different dates.

Comment: I just want the user data, but that includes the dotfiles such as those that control the appearance of the desktop.  I assumed that as long as I stick with my home directory only, I won't be picking up any graphics/wifi chip stuff.   The only question there is what files in my home directory are not owned by me.  And apparently there are files in /tmp that I also need.